# How to do line-breaks and line-wrapping with SDL-TTF?

Tags: sdl, sdl-ttf

I just started using `SDL2_ttf`. I've figured out how to get some text on the screen with `TTF_RenderText_Blended`, but how do can I get it to do line-breaks and automatic wrapping?

1. It doesn't seem to support `\n`; it just creates a space instead of going down a line. Is there a way to add support for this? Specifically, using the proper line-height of the text, not by multiple calls to RenderText at different Y coordinates.
2. Given an X, Y coordinate and a width, how can I have it automatically go down a line whenever that width is reached (breaking between words)?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Instead of using `TTF_RenderText_Blended`, use `TTF_RenderText_Blended_Wrapped`. It takes additional parameter: width in pixels after which the text will break into next line.

Comment: Is that part of the standard library? I can't find any documentation on it. If that exists, that's sweet.

Comment: It's within latest SDL_ttf. I cannot find proper documentation(dunno why there is no reference to it at all), but I can assure you that it works.

Comment: Must be in VCS then.....doesn't exist in the 2.0.11 sources. Hrm... Just downloaded 2.0.12 and it's there. Awesome.

Comment: To anyone else reading this: `\n` also works with the *_Wrapped functions.

Comment: There's a bug with this where if your text has no spaces it does not wrap.

Comment: Just wanna add more info. Mars is right, I checked via `nm -a /usr/local/lib/libSDL2_ttf.a` for symbol table; on macOS (after self compile and install, but should be similar location if use `brew`). There are `_TTF_RenderText_Blended_Wrapped`, `_TTF_RenderUNICODE_Blended_Wrapped`, `_TTF_RenderUTF8_Blended_Wrapped`, and there is no document whatsoever. Need to peek into source for function arguments.

Comment: `TTF_RenderText_Blended_Wrapped` will only put text on a new line if the string contains whitespace, and is only capable breaking lines on whitespace characters. It will not automatically break adjacent alphanumeric characters onto separate lines.

Answer (score 2):

SDL_TTF does not do wrapping, you have to write your own.

```
TTF_Font* ttf;
TTF_SizeText(ttf, "Hello World", &w, &h);
```

gives you the width and height of a string.

Comment: I was hoping for something a little more in-depth, but I guess I can write my own font-manager class.

Comment: I can have a go at some code if you like. C or C++?  I've always just split any long messages into several short ones.

Comment: C#, actually. I'm writing a wrapper around SDL2. You don't need to write any code, I just wanted to be aware of any pitfalls. The one thing I can't figure out how to do right now is kerning.

Comment: SDL-TTF should do that, it uses proportional fonts. I'd just use TTF_SizeText to get the legth of each string you add.

Comment: Doesn't look like it from my tests. If you write something like "AVA" the "V" should come over top of the "A"s a little bit, but it doesn't look like they overlap at all. Maybe I was just using a bad font though... will need to experiment more.